# Instalacion de librerias en latino

Tags: latino

Como puedo instalar librerias con latino? Queria usar la libreria mysql pero no tengo idea de como incluirla

Comment: Quizá te pueda servir: https://github.com/lenguaje-latino/latino-MySQL

Answer (score 0):

En cual sistema operativo deseas instalar la plugin de latino-MySQL? Si deseas instalarlo en linux, primero tienes que tener instalado las librerías de MySQL en tu sistema.

Paso 1: Aquí para instalarlo:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

Paso 2: Una vez instaladas estas librerías, pasas a compilar el plugin así:

```
git clone https://github.com/lenguaje-latino/Latino-MySQL
cd latino-mysql
sudo chmod +x instalar.sh
sudo bash instalar.sh
```

El segundo paso puede que también te funcionen para  macOS.

Para saber mas sobre el plugin de Latino-MySQL, puedes mirar el repo aquí, https://github.com/lenguaje-latino/latino-MySQL